# Upload File to Amazon S3 from Url [file does not exist error]

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, cloud-hosting

Currently I am using viddler for different service and videos uploading. I also would like to make a service for content backup on an amazon s3 server. For developing this service I used the AWS SDK for .NET. When I try to upload a file passing the URL as the file path it gives me the following error:
`"the specified file does not exist"`

My question is: Does the AWS SDK support content uploading from another domain to s3 programmatically or any other method?

My code:

```
PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
titledRequest.WithMetaData("title", "the title")
//.WithContentBody("this object has a title")
.WithBucketName(bucketName)
.WithFilePath("http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/2/2/9222D67F-7630-4F49-BD26-        476B51517FC1/FileFormatConverters.exe") //does url support? 
.WithTimeout(3600000)
.WithReadWriteTimeout(3600000)
.WithKey("test.ext");

using (S3Response responseWithMetadata = client.PutObject(titledRequest))
{
}
```

Comment: Why there is a space in your `WithFilePath` parameter?

Comment: @Dave its mistake
.WithFilePath("http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/2/2/9222D67F-7630-4F49-BD26-476B51517FC1/FileFormatConverters.exe")

i think the amazone s3 doest not support pull files request

Answer (score 0):

Uploads to S3 require the entire bytestream with the content-length metadata set. You would have to create a live buffer that receives data from the source url and pipe it to the S3 PutObject request asynchronously.

One of the ways you can do this is have two buffers to streamline the bytestream from the source into set chunk sizes that can be used as a part of the multipart upload.

The SDK, I doubt has support for this so you would have to implement this using REST calls to the AWS service.